# Do "switch_to_blog()" and "restore_current_blog()" re-run the filters?

Tags: multisite, filters, switch-to-blog

I've been working on a Wordrepss multisite network and came across very common requirement of displaying a common navigation menu across all sites.

> Use `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` before and after `wp_nav_menu(...)` respectively, right?

So did I. **But**, late I was in noticing that it re-ran (at-least but not limited to) `posts_results` and `the_posts` filters. So the `posts_results` filter would be called 3 times instead of 1 and would get following `$posts` parameter passed in.

**1st time:** The expected parameter. The post/posts to display on current page

**2nd time:** This call is probably result of `switch_to_blog()` call. This time the `posts_results` filter handler would be passed the menu items array.

**3rd time:** This call is probably result of `restore_current_blog()` call, and is the strangest. This time the `posts_results` filter handler would be passed, brace for it, the `pages` that are linked in the menu it just displayed in `2nd time`.

removing the switch/restore calls removes this behavior and the filters are called only one time.

I figured it out the hard way after noticing that the callbacks to aforementioned hooks kept executing multiple times and were getting unexpected `post_type` to them. I first took it as default behavior of multisite and tried to work around it by checking `post_type` and executing code only when it got the expected `post_type`. But after looking into it closely, I think it is an unexpected behavior since it is not documented anywhere and doesn't make much sense either.

My question,
Is this behavior unexpected?
If not then what is the use-case for this behavior?
If yes then how to avoid it?

I'm using latest version of Wordpress, version 4.3.

Any help regarding this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The typical answer to anything `switch_to_blog()` is — no it shouldn't, yes it is a mess. Simply put WP architecture doesn't posses the capability of making such clean switch from one blog to another in the runtime. It's a bit of wishful thinking — some things work, some very much break.

In your specific case it is a little puzzling why would query–related hooks fire, since the switch itself shouldn’t involve querying posts. The most reliable would be to dump *how* they are called up, for example using [`wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll update the question with debug backtrace shortly.